# Save watchface settings on both mobile and wearable

Tags: java, android, wear-os, persistent-storage, android-wear-data-api

I want to provide a Wear OS watchface that comes with an Android application, which controls several properties for the watchface. I set everything up in Android Studio, and I'm done with the mobile side and the watchface renderer. Now I face the issue of exchanging data between mobile and watch, because I'd like to send the properties set on my phone to the watch. I read something about a `DataItem`, and I guess that one is going to help me with the data exchange.

Now once the data is exchanged and the watchface is set up accordingly, I want both the app and the watchface to "remember" these settings for when they restart. Is there a way to persist `DataItems`, or are there other options (other than just saving it separately on both devices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataItem`s do persist, but they're not entirely reliable, and you still need a UI for configuration - ideally on both devices. I've opted for sharing a single XML file that renders into a `PreferenceScreen` on both, and I built something I call [`PrefSyncService`](https://github.com/StringMon/prefsyncservice) to automagically keep the `SharedPreferences` in sync between the two devices.

Comment: The information of DataItems persisting solves this issue I guess. A config UI on both devices doesn't really work out on my app, since it's just too much configuration do tap around on a small watch screen :D

Comment: `DataItem` persistence isn't entirely reliable, but you'll have to decide if it's good enough for your app. And `PrefSyncService` works fine one-way: do all your config on the phone, it'll sync those settings to the watch, and then you can access them through `SharedPreferences` there.

Comment: That sounds even better - Also I found that DataItems are implemented a lot differently from what I expected - so I'm going to look into that PrefSyncService once I got time.

Comment: Got everything to work just fine. After I understood how to use your PrefSyncService it was a pretty easy and quick implementation, so thanks a lot for that :)

(Might still suggest updating your docs, since it's not entirely obvious on which side certain things are supposed to be implemented, such as the PrefListener)

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd also be happy for you to send specific suggestions for doc updates, as it's not clear to me what, um, wasn't clear to you. 